# error when customing openstack dashaboard

Tags: openstack, dashboard, openstack-horizon

I'm use openstack queens and devstack,ubuntu16.04
I want to create a dashboard,when i use follow commands

> $ mkdir openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard
>   $ tox -e manage -- startdash mydashboard --target openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard

from openstack website https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/queens/contributor/tutorials/dashboard.html#the-quick-version

i get errors:

> js@dmdb-23:~/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon$ tox -e manage -- startdash mydashboard   --target openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard
>
> manage develop-inst-noop: /home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon
>
> manage installed: horizon==13.0.2.dev22
>
> manage run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='2095316472'
>
> manage runtests: commands[0] |
>   /home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon/.tox/manage/bin/python
>   /home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon/manage.py startdash
>   mydashboard --target openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):     File "/home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon/manage.py", line 18, in
>   
>       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>
> ImportError: No module named django.core.management   ERROR:
>   InvocationError for command
>   '/home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon/.tox/manage/bin/python
>   /home/js/Desktop/openstack.bak/stack/horizon/manage.py startdash
>   mydashboard --target openstack_dashboard/dashboards/mydashboard'
>   (exited with code 1)

[image]

This is the first time i answer questions,so the format may be poor,but i hope someone can help me ,thanks a lot.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is version of Django you have installed.  Check it.  Horizon currently requires Django 1.x.

Comment: thanks,the version of Django is 1.11.9